# where does Nuget download packages when PackageReference is enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

In visual studio  2017 i have enabled `PackageReference` so that package reference will be stored in csproj file instead of package.config file

I have added these 2 line in csproj file to enable PackageRefernce

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Now when i install any package using Nuget Package Manager, i see something like this

[image]

references with blue icon are added as package.

However i dont see any of these packages in `packages` folder under  solution directory. Moreover, if i right click on blue icon (i.e reference) and click on properties, the window the blank. I cannot see the path where its referencing from

So when does Visual Studio download the packages when package? reference is enabled

Answer (score 28, accepted):

looks like it installs the packages in `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\`

when packagereference in enabled

Comment: Can you change the location the packages are saved to?

Comment: For guys just want to get the path no matter which user, use %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\

Comment: @JoeLau had to to specify $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\ to get the reference working